# Convert excel file to pipe delimited file in python

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx

I know we can write a CSV file as a pipe delimited file using python's csv module, however I wanted to write my excel files as pipe delimited text file, is there a module similar to the csv module that can help me achieve this?

Comment: To read xlsx files, use the xlrd module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas module

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd

# read the content of your Excel file into a dataframe
df_sheet  = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=0) 

# write the content of your dataframe into a csv file with the right delimiter
df_sheet.to_csv ("test.csv", sep="|")
```